# questions about cudnn lrn backward possible implementation

Tags: cudnn

lrn's equation is as follows:

```
 y = x * pow(lrn_k + lrn_alpha/lrn_size * sum(Xj * Xj), -lrn_beta)
```

the cudnn's lrn backward api is

```
cudnnStatus_t cudnnLRNCrossChannelBackward(
cudnnHandle_t                    handle,
cudnnLRNDescriptor_t             normDesc,
cudnnLRNMode_t                   lrnMode,
const void                      *alpha,
const cudnnTensorDescriptor_t    yDesc,
const void                      *y,
const cudnnTensorDescriptor_t    dyDesc,
const void                      *dy,
const cudnnTensorDescriptor_t    xDesc,
const void                      *x,
const void                      *beta,
const cudnnTensorDescriptor_t    dxDesc,
void                            *dx)
```

I find there is no workspace in order to save scale which is implemented in caffe, which is

```
    scale = lrn_k + lrn_alpha/lrn_size * sum(Xj * Xj)
```

this variable is useful in order to calculate lrn backward. 
So I think maybe in the backward kernel will just calculate from y, x and lrn_beta in order to calculate this variable, the equation is similar like this:

```
   y/x = pow(scale, -lrn_beta)
   y/x = pow2(-lrn_beta * log2(scale))
   log2(scale) = -1/lrn_beta * log2(y/x)
   scale = pow2(-1/lrn_beta * log2(y/x))
```

when I use these equations to calculate scale, cuda kernel generate NAN, is there other method which calculate lrn backward without saving scale value in forward? And why my method is not stable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checked the ptx, this backforward pass still need to calculate the scale which is calculated in forward.